# Would like to execute a query once per day in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I would like my ASP.NET MVC app to execute a query once per day. What is the recommended way to do this?

My first thought is to put a timer in Global.asax that goes off every 24 hours, then call my query from the `Elapsed` handler. Any pitfalls with doing it this way? Is there a better way?

**Edit**

Let me add a little detail to what I'm trying to do. I'd specifically like the query to execute at midnight every day. If a day is missed (say due to sever maintenance or upgrading the app), that wouldn't be a major issue.

**Edit 2**

Couple more details:

1. The query is actually an INSERT, not a SELECT. The purpose is to add a "renewal" record for any member that is due to renew his/her membership at the end of the month.
2. I'm using SQL Server Compact (it's a very small database).

Comment: If you are running your website on a dedicated server, you can think of writing a windows service to run your query. This way you need not to worry about IIS restart. Even if you website is down for some reason, your service will still work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does it have to originate in the Web layer? Who'd be there to consume the HTML? Typically, periodic SQL queries are scheduled within the database. In case of MS SQL Server - via the SQL Agent job facility. SQL Server can even send e-mail.

RE: edit2: Should've told so right away. SQL Server Compact is not the same as SQL Server - for one, it does not have SQL Agent IIRC. Still, invoking the Web layer is an overkill. I'd use a Windows Scripting Host file (.js) in conjuction with Windows task scheduler. WSH files can connect to databases via ADO and do whatever they want - inserts, selects, anything.

To detect missed scheduled runs, introduce an extra table with a log of scheduled runs. Then on subsequent runs you can analyse the date of the last run and act accordingly.

Edit2: so no administrative access. You should really tell all those details in the question. In this case, I *would* go through the Web layer after all, but the scheduling would be on MY end - where I do have control. Have Task Scheduler run on your end and invoke an HTTP URL on the server. To invoke URLs, you can use something like the [free CURL utility](https://curl.haxx.se/). Running IE in scheduled manner has the disadvantage of leaving the window open.

IIS is not a scheduling engine.

Edit3 re:comment: sorry, I've misunderstood the nature of your setup. My own experiences have clouded my judgement :) Can you just run a check during every logon operation, and if it's been a while since the last maintenance operation, run it right then and there? How long does the maintenance take? If it's ~1min+, makes sense to run it in a worker thread, so that the logging-on user is not made wait.

Scheduling daily maintenance is a good idea in general, and it is implemented fairly often, but it seems you simply don't have the capability.

Comment: Seva, please see my second edit. I believe it does need to be in the web layer.

Comment: you can still do what you're looking for either directly in SQL Server, or alternatively by running a scheduled task that executes a custom .exe on your server.

Comment: @seva, thanks for updating your answer. One issue is that I don't have direct access to the server machine, only FTP access. I'm not sure I can implement your solution without being able to get on the machine. Please let me know if you think it can be done entirely my uploading files to the website directory, though.

Comment: @seva, it's hard to know what details to provide until you know what kind of answers you are going to get :) In any case, thank you for your help. I'm a little confused by your "Edit2". What do you mean by running the scheduling at "MY end"? I don't have a dedicated machine for this project that's up and running all the time, so I don't think that's going to work for me. As I said in my first edit, it's not critical that this query run every time or even at a specific time, it's just a maintenance-type task that needs to be done "fairly regularly", and daily seemed like a good base rate...

Comment: (cont) So, I'm thinking some kind of event in global.asax would probably work fine for my particular purposes if I set it up properly. The query I run will have no impact if no one is accessing the web site to see the results. So, if I schedule for midnight on July 11, and IIS is down at the time. It's fine if the query doesn't run until someone logs in at, say, 8 a.m...Hope that helps you understand better what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I do this very thing in my web apps, but use Asynchronous HTTP Handlers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx#Y512); I believe this would be recommended. I just start it off on application start and shut it down on application end (Global.asx).

The thing to remember is that you'll probably have to store the last time the query ran in the database because you'll loose track of that when your application pool recycles.

Comment: gangelo, thanks for your answer. I'll check out the link. Please check out the edit to my question.

Comment: @danm, regarding the edit: in that case, no need to store in database if its not that critical.  If you get stuck, email me and I can send you some code beginning of the week.  BTW, what that example does not show is the loop you will need to check the time and a "cancel loop" mechanism to shut it down on application end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this by putting some fake information in "Cache" and put the time period i want then handel the "_onCacheRemove" event do whatever i wanna do then recreate the "CacheItem" again:

e.g.

I put my tasks in Enum with the time that i wanna to rerun this task in seconds:

```
public enum ScheduledTasks
{
    CleanGameRequests = 120,
    CleanUpOnlineUsers = 6
}
```

then deal with them at  "Application_Start" :

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        // Adding the tasks i want at App_Start 
        // so if the application restarted my task will refreshed.
        AddTask(ScheduledTasks.CleanGameRequests);
        AddTask(ScheduledTasks.CleanUpOnlineUsers);
    }

    // event to handel
    private static CacheItemRemovedCallback _onCacheRemove;
    private void AddTask(ScheduledTasks task)
    {
        _onCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(task.ToString(), (int)task, null,
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((int)task), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, _onCacheRemove);
    }

    public void CacheItemRemoved(string key, object time, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
    {
        var task = (ScheduledTasks)Enum.Parse(typeof(ScheduledTasks), key);
        switch (task)
        {
            case ScheduledTasks.CleanGameRequests:
                // Do the concept that you wanna to do.
                GameRequest.CleanUp();
                break;
            case ScheduledTasks.CleanUpOnlineUsers:
                OnlineUsers.CleanUp();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        // Don't forget to recreate the "CacheItem" again.
        AddTask(task);
    }
```

> **Note:** You may make your time management as you want. In my case i
>   wanna these tasks to run every period
>   of time regardless of what time it is.
>
> In your case you should check the time
>   before then recreate the CacheItem
>   again.

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very active site chances are that IIS will bring your application down and there will be no process to execute your task.

Alternatives:

- just do that during/immediately after request that is close enough by time
- have external task that will trigger the operation on your site via GET/POST.
- reconfigure IIS to never recycle/stop your app pool. Than your timer has chance to execute.
- use some external service on the server to schedule the task ("at" or even SQL tasks).

Comment: Alexei, I added some more information to my question based in part on your answer. I like the idea of just checking the date/time on each request and seeing if the query is needed yet, then running it if it is. I'm thinking I could do this with an ActionFilter. What do you think?